# cannot get total sum of item in my cart

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
        $sql = "SELECT product_name, image, price, sum(price) AS subtotal  FROM 
        items WHERE id = '$key'
        ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            extract($item);

        }
    }
}
```

Im trying to get the sum of my cart but when I echo the $subtotal what im getting is not the sum but the price of only one item

Comment: I think ur sql query is wrong when you use the aggrigate functions you have to include the remaning columns in the group by clause.

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean Im new in coding, I tried to query it and its working with the same field. what im thinking is that my where clause only get one id per loop (the $key) so there is nothing to sum up?

but I can display the items that I added to my cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the total sum in different ways.

One way can be changing the query like this

```
$ids = array();

if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
        $ids[] = $key; //get all the ids
    }

    $ids = implode(',', $ids); //make the ids array a string like this 1,2,3...

    $sql = "SELECT product_name, image, price, sum(price) AS subtotal  FROM 
    items WHERE id IN ($ids)";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        extract($item);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT A.*, SUM(subtotal) AS grandTotal 
FROM (SELECT product_name, image, price, COUNT(*) quantity, price * COUNT(*) AS subtotal 
FROM items 
WHERE id IN ($ids) 
GROUP BY product_name, image, price) A;
```